# IcCube Reporting, How to format amCharts Bubble axis?

Tags: amcharts, iccube, iccube-reporting

Let's take a simple MDX:

```
 with 
 member Axis1 as '0.1', format_string='Percent'
 member Axis2 as '0.2', format_string='Percent'
 member value1 as '2532'
 select {Axis1, Axis2, value1} on 0,
 [Periode].[Periode].[All-M].&[2015] on 1
 from [Cube]
```

returning values :

[image]

Creating an amCharts Bubble widget with this gives the following :
[image]

Q: How can I format the Axis values (0.190  0.195  0.200 and so on...) like the ones shown in the balloon? (19.00%  19.50%  20.00% and so on...)

Comment: I'm not familiar with iccube, but it would be easily doable in amCharts. Do you have access to actual amCharts code that you can modify? I can provide instructions what you need to change in that case.

Comment: I don't really have access to amCharts code... But I can pass some parameters to it thru icCube... What would be the property I have to play with?

Comment: You'd need to pass in two parameters to a value axis: `unit` and `unitPosition`. The tricky part is that it's not a direct property of the chart, it's a property of the ValueAxis object which is contained in the `valueAxes` array in chart config, i.e. `valueAxes: [{ unit: "%", unitPosition: "right" }]` can you pass in something like that?

Comment: Thanks, I pasted your code in the "Vertical Axis" section of my icCube interface and have been able to replace '0.190' by '0.190%'... Now, to reflect the same format as in the balloon, the value should be multiplied by 100...

Comment: For that you'll need to use value axis' `labelFunction`. Something like this: `valueAxes: [{ "labelFunction": function(value) { return (value * 100) + "%"; } }]` http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#labelFunction

Comment: Thanks @martynasma, I found this function in between, but although I've been able to use it in a fiddle, It does not work from icCube... I get an error `This.labelFunction is not a function`... I think I need icCube Specialist...   @ic3?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it's only possible to use extra options in the chart configuration. To get percent labels on XY chart you should put this construction to (Widget->Edit->Widget->Advanced Properties->Extra Options):

```
:{
    valueAxes: [
        { "labelFunction": function(value) { return (value * 100) + "%"; } },
        { "labelFunction": function(value) { return (value * 100) + "%"; } }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Any idea on how to do this for both axes ?